# Laravel Dusk opens incorrect site URL

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, laravel-dusk

So I am running my site as `http://localhost:8080`, below is my test:

```
public function testExample() {
        $this->browse( function ( Browser $browser ) {
            $browser->visit( '/' )
                    ->assertTitle( 'Welcome to Mysite' );
        } );
    }
```

On running `php artisan dusk`, it opens wrong URL that is `http://localhost`. if I mention complete URL then it works.

How to make it open correct URL?

Comment: It should take the application URL from within your `config/app.php` or respectively `APP_URL` from within your `.env` file. Did you customize this parameter?

Answer (score 10):

Thanks @Sven for the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44533862/laravel-dusk-opens-incorrect-site-url#comment76114725_44533862).

1. Update `.env` file. Set `APP_URL` property
2. Check `config/app.php` file. The [`url` property](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.4/config/app.php#L54) should be like this `'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost')` (in my case that's was the problem)